# Creating a matrix such that each element is a quaternion in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix of random self-dual quaternions (4d numbers) in python. Each of these quaternions can be represented as a complex 2x2 matrix generated as follows:

```
X=np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)+np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)*1j
Y=np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)+np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1)*1j
quaternion=[[X][Y],[-Y.conj()][X.conj()]]
```

I would like to somehow run a loop creating n^2 of these random matrices, and then make each of them an element of an n x n matrix (Which will, of course, be 2n x 2n as each entry is a 2x2 matrix).
I tried appending them to a list and reshaping it to a matrix, but to no avail.
I hope I have articulated this clearly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `but to no avail.`  We prefer a better description of your efforts and failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 10
shape = [n,n,2,2]
```

```
real = np.random.normal(loc= 0, scale= 1, size= [n,n,2])
imgn = np.random.normal(loc= 0, scale= 1, size= [n,n,2]) * 1j

q1 = real + imgn                     # q1 = [[X], [Y]] where X and Y are imaginary numbers

q2 = q1[..., ::-1]                   # q2 = [[Y], [X]]
q2 = q2 * np.array([-1, 1])          # q2 = [[-Y], [X]]
q2 = q2.conj()                       # q2 = [[-Y.conj], [X.conj]]

dual = np.empty(shape, dtype= complex)
dual[:, :, 0, :] = q1
dual[:, :, 1, :] = q2

quaternions = dual
```

```
quaternions.shape

>>> (10, 10, 2, 2)
```

okay, so im familiar with quaternions and from your question i assume you're representing a quaternion with `1 x 2` array of two complex numbers. and with the `2 x 2` matrix it's dual?

Comment: @AdamGraham no looping would not be necessary, numpy uses vectorised operations, which in essence are extremely fast loops. so i would recommend you to use numpy. if you want 100 matrices, just set n = 10, if you found my answer helpful, pls accept my answer by clicking the green tick to on the left of my answer

there was also a logical error in my answer, i've fixed that too

Comment: just one more thing. I have been trying to understand how you constructed this matrix. While most of it is now clear, I do not understand what the line "dual=dual[...,::-1]" means. Are you excluding the final element of the last dimension? If so could you expand on the motivation behind that. Also it would be really helpful if you could clarify the motivation behind the use of [:,:,0,,:] and [:,:,1,;] in defining complex and dual. Thanks

Comment: @P4PL4 my mistake, because of my misunderstanding of what a dual is, i named the variables wrong. i've updated the variable names and added comments to make it easier to understand. p.s: `arr[..., ::-1]` means to reverse the last axis of 'arr'. `arr[:,:,i,:]` means that i am refrencing/assigining all the elements of `arr` whose position on 2nd last axis is `i`. this is specific to the way you have decided to format your `quaternions` array